# Redirect to External API for SSO authentication with parameters in laravel

Tags: laravel

I have a problem I want to redirect to SSO , they give me API with that we have to send two parameters one is username other is password

I tried some thing but seams it not working for me

```
 $client = new User();
     $response = Http::post('http://sso.com:0000/SSOREST/SSOAuthentication', [
          'json' => [
             'UserName' => 'vikram.vishvakarma',
              'Password' => 'VmlrcmQWETIzQA==',
           ],
         ]);
```

I don't no this is right or wrong

please help

I just want to redirect to sso page if username and password is right according to Sso

Comment: Please include `var_dump` of `$response` in the question.

Comment: Please don't post [duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75601654/redirect-to-external-api-for-sso-authentication-in-laravel).

Comment: @Top-Master sir i did and it respond 200 means ok     but it not redirect to SSO

Comment: @VikramVishvakarma the `$response` is a class, which's `var_dump(...)` and/or `dd(...)` should contain more than just `200`, that's valuable information, which's required to get better answer.

Answer (score 1):

To sign-in to external site by token coming from SSO `$response`.

In a controller, try:

```
$response = Http::post('http://sso.com:0000/SSOREST/SSOAuthentication', [
    'json' => [
        'UserName' => 'vikram.vishvakarma',
        'Password' => 'VmlrcmQWETIzQA==',
    ],
]);

$url = 'http://sso.com:0000/SSOREST/SSOAuthentication';
$url = $url . '?' . http_build_query([
    'token' => $response->json()['token_num'],
]);

return redirect()->away($url);
```

Above will redirect, but the `$url` is just an example, change that according to sso.com's API/Route requirements.

Comment: thank you sir for your reply IS REDIRECT to page but in network-payload is give me a token_num with username and my password      also it shows error on page" This site can’t provide a secure connection "

Comment: @VikramVishvakarma that token_num may be required to create URL, but for now try removing the "s" of httpS.

Comment: yes I removed it redirect to page but page just not open same error on that URL "This site can’t provide a secure connection"

Comment: @VikramVishvakarma the browser is blocking it for security reasons, and there should be a continue or accept-risk link/button somewhere

Comment: @VikramVishvakarma I hope sso.com is just a sample? Because it seems to be a domain waiting for sale.

Comment: no sir there is no buttton or link just content like  ---------------------------------------This site can’t provide a secure connection sso.com sent an invalid response.
Try running Windows Network Diagnostics.
ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

Comment: what is the role of token num in that how can i validate it         I guess when token num validate from both side than this side open

Comment: @VikramVishvakarma SSL error means it's yet HTTPS, try changing address bar manually to HTTP.

Comment: @VikramVishvakarma A token can be part of the URL, which part depends on the site's API/Routes, but I could not find sso.com's documentation.

Comment: sir i tried manually but it not redirect in controlller in change to http also in address bar      please give me other solution if any you know

Comment: sir site name is sso.rajasthan.gov.in

Comment: sorry i didn't provide you real name due to security hope you understand              site name is sso.rajasthan.gov.in

Comment: sir may be main reason is token

Comment: Undefined property: Illuminate\Http\Client\Response::$token_num                                       AGAIN ERROR SIR ;(

Comment: SIR $response and $url are same ? $response is API which i provided to you what about $url why it is same api here

Comment: @VikramVishvakarma see edit, use `->json()['token_num']` (I thought it may have magic-property support, like models).

Comment: @VikramVishvakarma "what about $url" that and it's `token` param are just a sample, because I could not yet find their route documentation.

Comment: Route::post('login-user', [LoginController::class, 'loginUser'])->name('login-user');         sir its my route in web.php

Comment: sir new error :"Undefined array key "token_num"    and this time it not redirect to api

Comment: @VikramVishvakarma "its my route": then, are you trying to "Redirect to External API" or login user to your own site?

Comment: @VikramVishvakarma if you want to login to your own site, using external SSO, then use: https://github.com/24Slides/laravel-saml2

Comment: sorry sir but its bot working

Comment: sir i will tell you very quickly about flow of my system ----- first when user enter the username and password on my login system (which is already has been saved in SSO portal which i want to redirect after login) then i want these username and password match the same at sso side than allow me to redirect there page        for this they give me API and with this Api two parameters will pass                     so this is how flow works

Comment: @VikramVishvakarma you said "in payload gives me a token_num", which means you can fix "Undefined array key `token_num`" by using the right path, for example, `->json()['data']['token_num']` (I mean, you did not send me `var_dump` of the `$response`, hence my answer is just an example, and does not include the right path to `token_num`).

Comment: @VikramVishvakarma Once you fix the path of `token_num`, you just need to ask the API provider about: **1.** "what route and/or URL does accept token_num", **2.** "what parameter-name does said route need for `token_num` to be passed as", **3.** "what is method of said route, does it accept GET method" (I can't answer these, and my answer includes dummy/placeholder instead).

Comment: @VikramVishvakarma My answer assumes said route/URL accepts GET method, else one would need to use JavaScript instead of a simple Laravel `redirect()`.

Comment: $SSOurl = 'http://sso.com:0000/SSOREST/SSOAuthentication';
            $Params = http_build_query([
                'UserName' => $request->input('Vikram.Vishvakarma'),
                'Password' => $request->input('VmlrcmFtMTIzQA=='),
                // Add more parameters as needed
            ]);
            $SSOurl .= '?' . $Params;

            // Redirect the user to the external API
            return redirect($SSOurl);

Comment: sir when i run the above code it give me three parameters in payload network         one is token and username and password

Comment: but it didn't redirect to page only that api in shown in browser url address bar

Comment: @VikramVishvakarma They have "REST" in their URL, which normally means that the route/URL will never login browser, it's for JavaScript authentication only. Their API needs to support [mentioned approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75612396/redirect-to-external-api-for-sso-authentication-with-parameters-in-laravel/75612939#comment133424805_75612939) for non-JavaScript use cases.

Comment: ok means the issue is not from our end     we are doing right code for redirection

Comment: sir i found that when call API it show shows a token number in inspect/network now i want to store that dynamic token and if token matches both side it redirect to my dashboard and values are in session